# Android add new form and button dynamically

Tags: android, forms, button

Currently working on an Android app. I want a page to have a button, and when clicked on, I want it to create a form. When they press the button again, it will create another form, and so on. Just like when you are on a website, and add your emails or anything, and you press "add" button, which will create a new input field each time.

Also, next to the input field has a name (same for each time) like

fieldName: [___input_field____] 
fieldName: [___input_field____] 
...

(+) //there is a button, and pressing this button will create a new form above.

I am not sure how to go about this. I want each input field to have a different ID, but is it possible? Each input field is going to be filled with a number, and in the end, I want to add all numbers in the form to find the average of them.

Comment: create an xml and inflate it programming

Comment: use fragments....

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but how can each field have a different ID?

Comment: set to some variable id to set its parent View and use their child using like this `((ImageView) ((LinearLayout) v).getChildAt(0)).setImageResource(categoryplace1[Arrays.asList(categoryitem).indexOf(name)]);`

Comment: Use fragments is best options for you to replace pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will be easier and cleaner create a child layout with your form and inflate that child every time you need a new form and to get each item you can use  `View.getChildAt(position);`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.android-examples.com/create-edittext-dynamically-using-java-file-in-android/

This link shows a simple way to add an edittext dynamically. For what you have mentioned above, you have to use edittext array and for each "add" click, create edittext like et[i] = new EditText()...

Then on final submit click retrieve edittext datas from this editext array